# Como pegar uma class com array JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Por exemplo, no HTML, tenho assim:

```
<ul class="benefits">
<li>Finalização rápida e fácil</li>
<li>Múltiplos endereços de envio</li>
<li>Acesso fácil a seu histórico de pedidos e status</li>
</ul>
```

Como podem ver, tem 3 li's, como pego a [0] a [1] e a [2] com JQuery?

Tentei algo estranho, mas como de esperado não deu certo:

```
$('ul.benefits li' + [0]).text('teste');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar usando o `.get`:

```js
console.log($('.benefits li').get(0));
console.log($('.benefits li').get(1));
console.log($('.benefits li').get(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="benefits">
<li>Finalização rápida e fácil</li>
<li>Múltiplos endereços de envio</li>
<li>Acesso fácil a seu histórico de pedidos e status</li>
</ul>
```

Ou pode usar o `eq`:

```js
console.log($('.benefits li:eq(0)').text());
console.log($('.benefits li:eq(1)').text());
console.log($('.benefits li:eq(2)').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="benefits">
<li>Finalização rápida e fácil</li>
<li>Múltiplos endereços de envio</li>
<li>Acesso fácil a seu histórico de pedidos e status</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Todas as respostas funcionaram, mas achei mais prático e rapido o uso do :eq, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para obter esses indices basta jogar em um array...

```js
var lis = [];
$('ul.benefits li').each(function(el){
 lis.push($(this).text());
})

console.log(lis);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="benefits">
<li>Finalização rápida e fácil</li>
<li>Múltiplos endereços de envio</li>
<li>Acesso fácil a seu histórico de pedidos e status</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível percorrer cada item e manipulá-lo usando `$.each`:

```js
$(".benefits li").each(function(idx, item){
  // para pegar
  console.log($(item).text());
  
  // para alterar
  $(item).text("texto " + idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="benefits">
  <li>Finalização rápida e fácil</li>
  <li>Múltiplos endereços de envio</li>
  <li>Acesso fácil a seu histórico de pedidos e status</li>
</ul>
```